# How to get current Locale in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I use this method

`LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()`

to get switched locale (Japanise) but it returns me English (default). How can I retrieve the jp_JP locale?

Answer (score 11):

```
//Return the Locale associated with the current thread,
// if any, or the   system default Locale else(English)   
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

so first you have to check Locale of your current thread.
If you want to set Locale in current thread then use this code :

```
setLocale(Locale locale); LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() will return jp_JP locale
```

Answer (score 5):

**RequestContextUtils**

This should allow you to get the current locale of your request:

```
RequestContextUtils.getLocaleResolver(request).resolveLocale(request);
```

Return the `LocaleResolver` that has been bound to the request by the `DispatcherServlet`.
@param `request` current HTTP request
@return the current `LocaleResolver`, or `{@code null}` if not found:

```
public static LocaleResolver getLocaleResolver(HttpServletRequest request) {
    return (LocaleResolver) request.getAttribute(DispatcherServlet.LOCALE_RESOLVER_ATTRIBUTE);
}
```

This will return a LocaleResolver from where you than can load the locale.

**LocaleContextHolder**

Or as metioned by: Mohammad tanvirul islam:

```
LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

You can have a look at the docu here:

1. *RequestContextUtils*: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html
2. *LocaleResolver*: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/LocaleResolver.html
3. *LocaleContextHolder*: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/i18n/LocaleContextHolder.html

Answer (score 3):

Giving a simple example for this.Let say you have resource as :Pick any one code

```
 @Autowired
    private MessageSource messageSource;

@GetMapping(path = "/hello-world-I18N")
    public String helloWorldInternationalize() {
        return messageSource.getMessage("good.morning.message", null, 
            LocaleContextHolder.getLocale());
    }


@GetMapping(path = "/hello-world-I18N")
public String helloWorldInternationalize(@RequestHeader(name = "Accept-Header", required = false) Locale locale) {
    return messageSource.getMessage("good.morning.message", null, locale);
}
```

Now in request with POSTMAN send in Headers as :
Accept-Language : US/FN etc any you want.

Configure one LocaleResolver for the same:

```
        @Bean
        public LocaleResolver localeResolver() {
            AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver();
            localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US); // set default to US
            return localeResolver;
        }
```

Now in application.properties file add
spring.messages.basename=message  // message is base name for your properties file.

Add more file in resource folder with name as : message_fr.properties, message.properties
and add the content here. like (good.morning.message = Bonjour)

the code will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to create a Locale object.To get the current Local object.

```
Locale locale = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

or

```
Locale locale;
```

to get the current language

```
Locale locale;
locale.getLanguage()

Locale locales = LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
locales.getLanguage();
```